# Deploying Pylons with Nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: python, nginx, pylons, paster

Is there a tutorial on how to deploy Pylons with Nginx?

I've been able to start nginx and then serve pylons to :8080 with paster serve development.ini

However, I can't seem to do other stuff as pylons locks me into that serve mode.  If I try to CTRL+Z out of pylons serving to do other stuff on my server, pylons goes down.

There must be a different method of deployment.

PS - I've done all this:
http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Running+Pylons+with+NGINX?showComments=true#comments

I just have no clue what to do with the Pylons app other than paster serve.  Not sure if tehre is a different method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run Pylons in daemon mode.

```
paster serve development.ini --daemon
```

Comment: Yes supervisord makes it much easier

Answer (score 2):

Running Pylons with nginx tutorial found here:
wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Running+Pylons+with+NGINX

Pylons on Nginx with Memcached and SSI:
http://www.reshetseret.com/app/blog/?p=3

UPDATE: link is broken, here is google cached version:
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.reshetseret.com/app/blog/